# MySQL Get the percentage of rows where field x equals y

Tags: mysql, database

I'm stuck on how to achieve the following.

> Each row in my subscribers table has 2 nullable fields: type1 and type3. which is null or 1.

I'm can't get my head around on how to create a query that checks the percentage of rows for each of the 2 options

My database looks like this.

```
+---------------+-------+-------+
|     email     | type1 | type2 |
+---------------+-------+-------+
| person1@email | 1     | null  |
| person2@email | null  | 1     |
| person3@email | 1     | 1     |
+---------------+-------+-------+
```

My ideal query returns the following result.

```
+--------+----------------+
|  Type  | Amount of rows |
+--------+----------------+
| type1  | 40%            |
| type2  | 60%            |
+--------+----------------+
```

Comment: Can you post what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I dont understand the result. What's the logic here?

Comment: type1 has 2 non null values as type2. So why percentage is 40/60? shouldn't 50/50 ? What is your logic?

Answer (score 2):

```
count(x)
```

returns the number of rows with not-null values of x.

Therefore, you could use:

```
SELECT count(type1) as t1, count(type2) as t2, count(*) as nrows
```

And you display:

```
100*t1/nrows
100*t2/nrows
```

Now, you want the result formatted differently. It is your problem, since the job of a database is to handle data, not formatting, display, or cosmetics. It does not matter in what column/row format the data is returned, as long as it is returned in the most efficient way possible. Display and presentation are the application's job.

If you insist,

```
SELECT 'type1', 100*count(type1)/count(*)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'type2', 100*count(type2)/count(*)
```

Of course, it will be twice as slow.

Comment: In point of fact, he didn't request a specific viewing format, but a specific relational format, which is well within the purview of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM TABLE WHERE A = B
```

Then divide it by the result of 
`SELECT COUNT (*) FROM TABLE`

and multiple by 100

Answer (score 0):

The query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(COUNT(type1)*100/COUNT(email), "%") AS `type1`, CONCAT(COUNT(type2)*100/COUNT(email), "%") AS `type2`
```

Should return:

```
+-------+-------+
| type1 | type2 |
+-------+-------+
| '40%' | '40%' |
+-------+-------+
```

If you want that pivoted to present as:

```
+---------+-------+
|  type   | pct   |
+---------+-------+
| 'type1' | '40%' |
+---------+-------+
| 'type2' | '40%' |
+---------+-------+
```

then you might make that `SELECT` into a `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ... FROM SELECT` to store the first result set in a temporary table, and then `SELECT ... UNION ALL ... SELECT` as @peufeu suggests, but without the performance penalty that comes from running the underlying query multiple times.